# r - Subsetting time-series data.frame based on time and threshold

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, subset

How would you subset a time-series data.frame based on time and a threshold value?

I have this data:

```
year <- seq(2000, 2009, 1)
v1 <- sample(1:10, 10, replace=T)
df <- data.frame(year, v1)
```

That looks like this:

```
> df
  year v1
1  2000  9
2  2001  4
3  2002  5
4  2003  4
5  2004  5
6  2005  3
7  2006  3
8  2007  3
9  2008  9
10 2009  6
```

I want to subset the data by groups of sequential years for which the summed score on `v1` exceeds the value of 10.

On this example data the first subset should hold observations of the year 2000 & 2001. The second subset should hold the observations of year 2002, 2003 and 2004.

The real data has about 8 million observations covering 120 years.

Comment: Please use `set.seed` when create examples using `sample`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement a customized `cumsum` using `Reduce` function, reset the sum when the total exceeds 10 and at same time increment a count as group variable:

```
library(data.table)
transpose(Reduce(function(x, y) if(x[1] > 10) c(y, x[2]+1) else c(x[1] + y, x[2]), 
                 init = c(0, 1), df$v1, accumulate = T))[[2]][-1]

# here the init parameter will take two parameters, the first one keep track of the cumsum,
# and the second one serves as a group variable, when the sum exceeds 10, reset the sum to 
# zero and increase the group variable by one

# [1] 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4
```

It takes around 20 seconds to run over 10 million observations vector:

```
v = sample(1:10, 10000000, replace = T)
system.time(transpose(Reduce(function(x, y) if(x[1] > 10) c(y, x[2]+1) else c(x[1] + y, x[2]), init = c(0, 1), v, accumulate = T))[[2]])

#   user  system elapsed 
# 19.509   0.552  20.081
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. This works great and is the kind of answer I am looking for. When I use this code, the output has 1 more observations than the `df`. Where do you think this comes from?

Comment: Ahh, nice catch. It comes from the initial parameter passed to the `Reduce` function. You can exclude it with `transpose(Reduce(function(x, y) if(x[1] > 10) c(y, x[2]+1) else c(x[1] + y, x[2]), init = c(0, 1), df$v1, accumulate = T))[[2]][-1]`.